# Performing advanced http requests in rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have the following objects:

```
class Question {
    idQuestion: string;
    question: string;
    typeQuestion: string;
}

class Answer {
    idAnswer: string;
    idQuestion: string;
    answer: string;
}

class Option {
    idOption: string;
    idQuestion: string;
    option;
}
```

And I want to populate the following object:

```
class QuestionOptionsAnswer {
    question: Question;
    answer: Answer;
    options: Option[];
}
```

For now, I have a service for each kind of object, so we can illustrate it in the following way:

```
questionService.getQuestions();
answerService.getAnswers();
optionService.getOptions();
```

To populate a `questionoptionsanswer` object I have doing nested requests:

```
questionService.getQuestions()
    .subscribe(
        answerService.getAnswers()
           .subscribe(
               optionService.getOptions()
                  .subscribe();
           )
    )
```

I can populate correctly the `questionoptionsanswer` object, but is is slow, so I think I am making a bad approach. The idea behind having a `questionoptionsanswer` is for rendering in a easy way the `html` with angular2 directives.

I read about `flatMap`, `switchMap`, `forkJoin` but I am not quite sure in how to use them.

Which could be a good approach to load this data?

`questionoptionsanswer` will have a question object, an answer associated with it, and its possible options depending on the `typeQuestion` i.e: select, radio, multiple, etc.

Comment: The real question is whether you need to call the requests in this order. In other words does response from one HTTP request influence the next HTTP request?

Comment: The are not independent. Answers and options depends on each question, in other words: each question have an answer and options (depending on the `typeQuestion`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to call the first request and wait for its response and then call the two other requests (for options and the answer) at the same time.

Since I want to know when both responses are ready I'll use [`Observable.forkJoin()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin) operator that emits a single array with all values of source Observables when they completed and then add data to the `qoa` variable that I'll just pass to the Observer when it subscribes.

Operators such `concat()` or `concatMap()` are good to make multiple HTTP calls in order but not very useful when you need to create multiple Observable to construct one large response you want to emit (`QuestionOptionsAnswer` in your case).

I also used `Observable.of(...)` to simulate HTTP requests. I don't know what's your usecase so you'll maybe don't use `Observable.create()` and use `Subject` instead:

```
function getQOA() {
    return Observable.create(observer => {

        Observable.of({ question_id: '1' }).subscribe(response => {
            var qoa = new QuestionOptionsAnswer();
            let question = new Question();
            question.idQuestion = response.question_id;

            qoa.question = question;

            let obs1 = Observable.of({ answer_id: '1', answer: 'bla' });
            let obs2 = Observable.of([{ option_id: '1', option: 'ble' }]);

            Observable.forkJoin(obs1, obs2).subscribe(responses => {
                let [answerResponse, optionsResponse] = responses;

                let answer = new Answer();
                answer.idAnswer = answerResponse.answer_id;
                answer.answer = answerResponse.answer;
                qoa.answer = answer;

                qoa.options = optionsResponse.map(o => {
                    let option = new Option();
                    option.idOption = o.option_id;
                    option.option = o.option;
                    return option;
                });

                observer.next(qoa);
            });
        });
    });
}

getQOA().subscribe(qoa => console.log(qoa));
```

Prints to console:

```
QuestionOptionsAnswer {
  question: Question { idQuestion: '1' },
  answer: Answer { idAnswer: '1', answer: 'bla' },
  options: [ Option { idOption: '1', option: 'ble' } ] }
```