# Cascading ajax calls with RxJs

Tags: javascript, rxjs

How can I cascade RxJs calls to retrieve data from this contrived service.

First request goes to /customer/1

/customer/:id

**Response:**

```
{
   Name: "Tom",
   Invoices: [1,3],
   Orders: [5,6]
}
```

In the customer response there are 2 InvoiceIds that we use to access second service:

/invoices/:id

**Response**

```
{
  Id: 1,
  Amount: 10
}
```

In the customer response there are 2 OrderIds that we use to access third service:

/orders/:id

**Response**

```
{
  Id:2,
  Date: '2016-11-12'        
}
```

At the end I would like to kome up with an object looking like this:

```
{
   Name: "Tom",
   Invoices: [
    {
      Id: 1,
      Amount: 10
    },
    {
      Id: 3,
      Amount: 5
    }],
   Orders: [
   {
     Id:5,
     Date: '2016-11-12'        
   },
   {
     Id:6,
     Date: '2016-11-12'        
   }]
}
```

How can I pass the ids through the pipeline so that the dependant objects are retrieved.

My gut feeling tells me I should probably use the flatMap operator, but I am totally uncertain how this could all work together.

```
var ajax = Rx.DOM.getJSON('/api/customers/1')
    .flatMap(p => p.Invoices.map(x =>
        Rx.DOM.getJSON('/api/invoices/' + x)
        ));
```

Comment: `Rx` is probably not the correct tool for the job here. Use Promises and `fetch()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical use-case where you need to construct a response out of several HTTP calls:

```
const Observable = Rx.Observable;

var customerObs = Observable.create(observer => {
    Observable.of({Name: "Tom", Invoices: [1,3], Orders: [5,6]})
        .subscribe(response => {
            var result  = {
                Name: response.Name,
                Invoices: [],
                Orders: [],
            };

            let invoicesObs = Observable.from(response.Invoices)
                .flatMap(id => Observable.of({ Id: Math.round(Math.random() * 50), Amount: Math.round(Math.random() * 500) }).delay(500))
                .toArray();

            let ordersObs = Observable.from(response.Orders)
                .flatMap(id => Observable.of({ Id: Math.round(Math.random() * 50), Amount: Math.round(Math.random() * 500) }).delay(400))
                .toArray();

            Observable.forkJoin(invoicesObs, ordersObs).subscribe(responses => {
                result.Invoices = responses[0];
                result.Orders = responses[1];

                observer.next(result);
            });

        });
});

customerObs.subscribe(customer => console.log(customer));
```

See live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/martinsikora/uc1246cx/

I'm using `Observable.of()` to simulate HTTP requests, `flatMap()` to turn each invoice/order id into an Observable (another HTTP request) that are reemitted and then `toArray()` to collect all values emitted from an operator chain and reemit them in a single array (just because it's convenient).

Operator `forkJoin()` waits until all source Observables complete and then emits their last value as an array (so we haw array of arrays in `responses`).

See a similar question: [Performing advanced http requests in rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343835/performing-advanced-http-requests-in-rxjs)

Comment: That's getting really close. I replaced the Observable.Of calls with the proper Rx.DOM.getJSON('/api/orders/' + id) calls. customerObs.subscribe is resolving faster than the network calls of getJSON. That way Orders and Invoces are still empty when console.log is executed. Do I need to Join them somehow?

Comment: @Marius Ah, you're right! Ideally with `forkJoin()`, see my updated answer.

Comment: @martin In case you would use API calls, how would you change that code? Is `Observable.create()` then still necessary?