# Object assign with rxjs5

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, rxjs, rxjs5

Hy, what is functional way to create object and use values from rxjs5 observables?

```
let _id = myObservableOne.pluck('id')
let _name = myObservableSecond.pluck('name')
let _path = myObservableThird.pluck('path')

let newObj = {
   id: _id,
   name: _name,
   path: _path
}
```

Comment: Answers to similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346728/merge-subarrays-using-observables/40347238#40347238, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250882/subscribing-to-a-nested-observable/40257871#40257871, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343835/performing-advanced-http-requests-in-rxjs/40346998#40346998

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending if the rate of value emissions is equal for all three observables the [.zip()](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/zip.md) operator might do what you need:

```
const idStream = myObservableOne.pluck('id')
const nameStream = myObservableSecond.pluck('name')
const pathStream = myObservableThird.pluck('path')

Rx.Observable.zip(
  idStream,
  nameStream,
  pathStream,
  (id, name, path) => ({ id, name, path})
)
.subscribe(console.log);
```